# Few memory leaks in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, memory-leaks, facebook-android-sdk

I tried to make social module for my app, something like wrapper, that will contain Google+,Facebook and twitter integration templates.

Now I am working with Facebook SDK and decided to use LeakCanary in my app, after successful log in I rotated the device few times, and see the following information:

[image]

Here is MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setFragment();

}
private void setFragment(){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

Here is how I log in to Facebook:

```
 public void configureFacebook(@NonNull Fragment fragment,
                              @Nullable String permissions, @Nullable String requestFields) {
    setPermissionAndRequestFields(permissions, requestFields);
    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(fragment, Arrays.asList(this.permissions));
    loginManager=null;

}
```

I tried log in using Login Button too, in this case I catch this issue and new one, with following info:

[image]

Here is how I log in using LoginButton.class:

```
  public void configureFacebook(@NonNull Fragment fragment,
                              @Nullable String permissions, @Nullable String requestFields, @NonNull LoginButton button) {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setFbButton(button);
    setPermissionAndRequestFields(permissions, requestFields);
    fbButton.setFragment(fragment);
    fbButton.setReadPermissions(this.permissions);
    fbButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);

}
```

I can't figure out how to fix those issues. What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: Leak in Facebook Activity.class has been shown without the rotation device.

Comment: Hey Denis. I am using Leaky Canary as well and I am facing the exact same issue. Any progress/solution to this ??

Comment: @Rohan, Hi! I moved to the last version of the facebook sdk, but I not checked it with LeakCanary, in my project I had no choice and I use this sdk with leaks.

Comment: I too  am using the latest facebook sdk.  I get logs which tell me both FacebookActivity has leaked as well as the leak related to the LoginManager. I have no clue how to solve these issues at the moment.

Comment: @Rohan, the same story with me, and I haven't idea when FB fix that, in my case leak was a few KB per minute

Comment: Hi @Denis. I was mistaken. I was not using the latest sdk. I was using 4.1.0. I updated it to 4.7.0 and I think this issue has been fixed. Can you please try this out and confirm it.

Comment: @Rohan, Hi, okey it possible, I'll try it, but a little bit later

Comment: Alright. I shall add this as an answer. Please accept it if it is indeed fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. It seems this issue does not occur if you have the Facebook app installed - I think they might have fixed this since it used to happen here before. However, if you do not have the app and the login dialog pops up, it still occurs!! I hope there is a fix to this ASAP.

Comment: Can confirm @Rohan. When there is no facebook app installed and the app opens facebook dialog in a webview, this leak happens on the latest version of fb sdk (v4.7.0).

Comment: Using faceboook SDK 4.10.1. I am still seeing memory leak on loginButton.0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@321303552 (0x1326b400)}
1 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@324723936 (0x135ae4e0)}
receiver = {com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver@862767904 (0x336ccb20)}
this$0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@862767872 (0x336ccb00)}
this$0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton@862774272 (0x336ce400)}
broadcastManager = {android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@855629248 (0x32ffddc0)}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they may have fixed this for Facebook SDK Version 4.2.0. [see here](https://github.com/segoh/facebook-android-sdk/commit/b4c67f8a5e29bc18726d91998b574d5f669d137e)

Updating the Facebook SDK may be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, but commit is dated Jun 2, I tested this less than a month ago

Comment: What version of the Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: Not OP. Just tried 4.2.0, it still leaks, the same as the first screenshot.

Comment: Ok, well it was worth a shot. That doesn't surprise me that it still leaks lol. 4.2.0 is also not the latest version. They claim to fix a few more memory leaks in a later release. However, when I updated it broke everything. I would recommend staying away from the facebook SDK unless you need an easy way to login/logout if you don't want to keep up with accounts yourself. I've been working with it for the past few months and it's a complete headache and at this point seems like they are only taking features away with every new release.

Comment: Using faceboook SDK 4.10.1. I am still seeing memory leak on loginButton.0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@321303552 (0x1326b400)} 1 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@324723936 (0x135ae4e0)} receiver = {com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver@862767904 (0x336ccb20)} this$0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@862767872 (0x336ccb00)} this$0 = {com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton@862774272 (0x336ce400)} broadcastManager = {android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@855629248 (0x32ffddc0)}

Answer (score 1):

I updated it to 4.7.0 and I think this issue has been fixed.

Comment: @Denis.  Oops. It seems this issue does not occur if you have the Facebook app installed - I think they might have fixed this since it used to happen here before. However, if you do not have the app and the login dialog pops up, it still occurs!! I hope there is a fix to this ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in 4.10. I tried without facebook app and checked with memory manager.